# Adding <link /> tags to the <head> section in meteor application

Tags: meteor

I have such template:

```
<template name="sidebar">
    <ul class="sidenav-list">
        {{#each links}}
        <li draggable="true" class="sidenav-list-item">
            <a href="{{link}}" class="sidenav-list-item__link">
                {{ name }}
            </a>
        </li>
        {{/each}}
    </ul>
</template>
```

And now I need to add `<link rel="prefetch" href="{{link}}" />` to `<head>` section for every single link from `links` array.

Adding a `<head>` tag inside the template doesn't help. Any ideas how to do it?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

This isn't supported yet:

> https://github.com/meteor/meteor/issues/266

However, you can add things to the `<head>` element using normal DOM manipulation, preferably using `Meteor.startup`. See the reactive example given in the link above.

Comment: Yeah, elements can be added using normal DOM manipulation, but links prefetching doesn't work anyway.