# How do you include a tag in the head of Meteor.js app at initial page load?

Tags: meteor, mobile-website, meteor-blaze

In particular, I'd like to add

```
<meta name="viewport" content="user-scalable=no, width=device-width, maximum-scale=1, initial-scale=1, minimum-scale=1">
```

and when I insert it into the head from JS, I'm still able to scroll horizontally on mobile browsers, so I'm guessing it needs to be in the head a load time.

Comment: See answer for this : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19093872/adding-link-tags-to-the-head-section-in-meteor-application

Comment: Try chaing user-scalable to 0 instead of no

Comment: The other question refers to a supported method of dynamic head insertion, post-page load. I'm looking to add a static tag before page load. Changing "no" to "0" had no effect.

Comment: What happens when you just put it inside `<head>` block?

Comment: Strips off <head> (well, either Meteor or Chrome does that) and puts content in body.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Place it in a `<head>` block outside of a `<template>` tag in any `.html` file.

Answer (score 2):

Try using [inject-initial](https://github.com/gadicc/meteor-inject-initial/) atmosphere package to have your `meta` tag present on the initial load.